# countif over 2 columns to display text when there is >1 duplicate in both cells

Tags: excel-2010, formulas, countif

I am currently using the following formula, which works but is giving me a false result.

**strong text**=IF(ISBLANK(E1)," ",IF(COUNTIF($E:$E,E1)>1,"duplicate","unique"))

I have several weeks of dates in one column and case numbers in another. (The case number starts at 0001 at midnight then it goes back to 0001 again at 00:01hrs). Therefore the case number will be repeated on a different day, but also may exist more than once on a specific day.

Where there is case number appearing >1 on a given date eg 2x "555" on 1/5/14. I want it to show "duplicate", but not when there is one "555" also on say 2/5/14, that would need to show unique

I am having no luck adapting an existing formula Ive found questions on which are similar.  I basically need an adaption with maybe an AND function perhaps? btw There is hundreds of lines of data of which I am pivoting, so I need to be able to filter off the duplicate/unique column to get figures for both.

Help would be much appreciated

Dee

Comment: use [COUNTIFs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of excel way of writing formulas but have you tried it in an algorithmic way ?

Write it down as an algorithm and then translate it to excel.

Comment: no I haven't, very new to all this so I have limited knowledge